# C Programming - Store all number generation in a given file

Tags: c, visual-studio, store

I've been set on a task to extend my original program (which displays six statements on the random generation of numbers in a dice) to store all number generated values into an external file. I've tried a few times but I don't understand the coding syntax for opening, saving and reading to an external file. All the altered coding has is in relation to creating a new file e.g. fprintf. I can send the original coding if it needed. Thanks in advance.

```
//Mini Project 1 | Make Your own Dice Program...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> // Allows srand() to generate different numbers each time

int table1(); // Declaration of function

//External Variable | Main Content of Code |(Array assigner, Number Counter, Prints Statements of each number counter)
int table1()
{
  //Lists of integer variables
  int num_of_nums = 60, c1 = 0, c2 = 0, c3 = 0, c4 = 0, c5 = 0, c6 = 0, upper_limit = 6;
  
  FILE *fp;

  //Main Printf Statement
   printf("\nWhich numbers appeared when a dice is thrown 60 times:\n ");

   int randArray[num_of_nums],v; //Creates array and counter variable
   for(v=0;v<num_of_nums;v++)
     randArray[v]= ((rand() % upper_limit)+1);   //Generate number from 1 to 6 in each position of the array until it reaches num_of_nums

     // For Loop | If Statement | Raises a Count Variable
   for(v=0;v<num_of_nums;v++)
   {
     if (randArray[v] == 1)
     c1++;
     if (randArray[v] == 2)
     c2++;
     if (randArray[v] == 3)
     c3++;
     if (randArray[v] == 4)
     c4++;
     if (randArray[v] == 5)
     c5++;
     if (randArray[v] == 6)
     c6++;
   }
   
   //MAIN PRINTF | Number "x" has been generated "y" times... ("y" is the counted variable e.g. c1)
   fprintf(fp,"\nNumber 1 has been generated %d times", c1);
   fprintf(fp,"\nNumber 2 has been generated %d times", c2);
   fprintf(fp,"\nNumber 3 has been generated %d times", c3);
   fprintf(fp,"\nNumber 4 has been generated %d times", c4);
   fprintf(fp,"\nNumber 5 has been generated %d times", c5);
   fprintf(fp,"\nNumber 6 has been generated %d times\n", c6);

   // Additional Work | Table Displaying The Counted Values
   printf("\nTable displaying the number of times each number was rolled...\n");
   printf("\n#1\t#2\t#3\t#4\t#5\t#6");
   printf("\n%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6);
   return 0;
}

//MAIN FUNCTION | DO LOOP | LOOPS EXTERNAL FUNCTIO 10 TIMES
int main(void)
 {
  int ch;
  FILE *fp;
  char filename[20];
  printf("\nEnter the name of the file...  ");
  scanf("%19s",filename);//File name cannot have spaces
  fp=fopen(filename, "r");
  if(fp==NULL) 
  {
  printf("\nError! File did not open.\n");
  return 1;
  }
  while((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
  putchar(ch);
  }

   int v = 0;
  srand(time(NULL));
  do
  {
    table1(); //External Variable 
    v++; //v+1
  }
  while (v < 10);

  fclose(fp);
  printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your `table1()` function, you assume that the file is already open, which is false. What you need to do is either pass the file pointer as an arguments to the function, but note that you have opened it using `"r"` mode, which will only read content from the file, maybe what you are looking for is `"r+"` which will both read and write to the file.

Comment: @alex01011 should i create another function just for File *fp etc?

Comment: You can just pass it as an argument, `int table1(FILE *fp)`